# Sudden Doctrine/JMSSerializer annotation failure

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, jmsserializerbundle

I suddenly got various

> [Semantical Error] The annotation "@\JMS\Serializer\Annotation\XXX" in  property YYY does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded
>   while the servers where still running the same version of my code.

In fact, 2 of my servers have been up since Dec.23 and they're fine. Only servers that got deployed since 24th are bugging, whereas using the same git tag, hinting toward vendor code.

My first guess was JMS was updated and my composer.lock is s**t.

But JSM Serializer's last change seems to be 1 year old.

Looking for insight on that kind of error or recent dependency updates.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a culprit in dependencies for now... but composer 1.3.0 was released around the time it all started. So maybe it's not what composer downloads, but composer itself.

Not solved yet.